# How to fix Call to undefined method Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register() .. My phot-gallery by 10web plugin is giving this error

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor, photo-gallery

My website suddenly started giving

> Call to undefined method Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register()

I haven't upgraded Elementor for it to break. Currently it is running v3.2.4.

I have already tried to activate and deactivate the plugin and found my 10web plugin photo gallery is the culprit. It was working fine, then suddenly it went down.

The error shows like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Elementor\Widgets_Manager::register() in /wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/admin/controllers/elementorWidget.php:145 
at line 145 
\Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register( new BWGElementor() );

Stack trace: 
#0 /wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/photo-gallery.php(324): require_once() 
#1 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): BWG->register_elementor_widgets(Object(Elementor\Widgets_Manager)) 
#2 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#3 /wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#4 /wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/managers/widgets.php(99): do_action('elementor/widge...', Object(Elementor\Widgets_Manager)) 
#5 /wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/managers/widgets.php(235): Elementor\Widgets_Manager->init_widgets() 
#6 /wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/elements/column.php(1032): Elementor\Widgets_Manager->get in /wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/admin/controllers/elementorWidget.php on line 145
```